# Witcher 3: stuck at the Morkvarg quest

Tags: the-witcher-3

I found myself in the middle of the Morkvarg quest without even realizing it's a side quest. I'm stuck at it, and the problem is, I cannot kill Morkvarg (my attacks don't do much to him, but 2-3 attacks from him kills me). I have been searching a little bit to find how to finish this quest; however, everything I have found so far  includes killing Morkvarg, which I cannot do.

At this point I'm happy even to drop out of this quest and continue the game, but I don't know how to drop out of a quest (and doesn't seem like I have a saved version immediately before the quest started)

Any tip will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your a little bit of a lower level and not ready to take him on. A good idea in this case would be to leave and come back later at a higher level.

Upgraded Quen really helps against big enemies, it can help with their initial hits and lets you roll away after you get caught.

Also make sure to use your oils on your silver sword, you can inflict more damage with the correct oil.

There's nothing you can about talking him down, you'll have to initiate combat to calm him down no matter how you finish the quest. So if you can't stand in the battle for long, come back after you're a higher level and have better equipment.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer helps. Is it possible to finish the quest without killing him? I can fight and stay alive, but cannot kill him. Also, just to make sure I understand your suggestion: what does "leave and comeback later" mean? Does it mean to select the main quest from the menu and continue from there? Thanks!

Comment: @crazylazy Yes, you can go do other quests, fight to level up, follow the main story, whatever you want to do. No, it's not possible to finish the quest without fighting him. There are ways to not KILL him, but you will have to fight him to at least calm him down and talk to him again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if there's a red skull above the enemy, they are way beyond your level and you have very slim chance of winning. The game should make this perfectly clear first time you run into it.

From what I remember, the first quest in Skellige is fairly low level, but ideally you shouldn't go there until you have completed all of the main story quests in Novigrad. If you head to Skellige before that, it will be very hard.

Also, when you find yourself doing poor damage, make sure to check that your sword is up to date. You should always have one with a level close to the character level. Preferably relic or witcher set, with some runes. If you haven't gotten a new one for 10 levels or so, then you'll do poor damage. This is much more important than using the right oils and signs.